# Port Vimeo Upload PHP POST Request

Tags: php, rest, oauth, vimeo

I am working on porting the Vimeo PHP library https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib to ColdFusion for a client and have successfully been able to translate everything except the video upload POST request. The PHP lib uses cURL like this:

```
    $params = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key'     => $this->_consumer_key,
        'oauth_token'            => $this->_token,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp'        => time(),
        'oauth_nonce'            => $this->_generateNonce(),
        'oauth_version'          => '1.0',
        'ticket_id'              => $ticket,
        'chunk_id'               => $i
    );

    // Generate the OAuth signature
    $params = array_merge($params, array(
        'oauth_signature' => $this->_generateSignature($params, 'POST', self::API_REST_URL),
        'file_data'       => '@'.$chunk['file'] // don't include the file in the signature
    ));

    // Post the file
    $curl = curl_init($endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $rsp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in cfscript but you can specify the file as a cfhttpparam.

```
<cfhttp url="something.com">
<cfhttpparam type="file" file="c:\temp\myfile"/>
</cfhttp>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Awesome... after seeing your post I ran off and tried some script based cfhttp :)  I use script for most things but I'd never tried it for cfhttp.